# project job scheduling: Multiple job parallel problems

Tags: optaplanner

In the same project, I don't want two jobs to run in parallel. How should I design it?
Is there a rule in the drl file that does not allow two jobs under the same project to run at the same time?
If there is no such thing, how should two jobs under the same project not run simultaneously?

```
rule "nonrenewableResourceCapacity"
    when
        $resource : Resource(renewable == false, $capacity : capacity)
        accumulate(
            ResourceRequirement(resource == $resource,
                    $executionMode : executionMode,
                    $requirement : requirement)
            and Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode);
            $used : sum($requirement);
            $used > $capacity
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, $capacity - $used);
end

rule "renewableResourceUsedDay"
        salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
    when
        ResourceRequirement(resourceRenewable == true, $executionMode : executionMode, $resource : resource)
        Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode,
                $startDate : startDate, $endDate : endDate)
    then
        for (int i = $startDate; i < $endDate; i++) {
            insertLogical(new RenewableResourceUsedDay($resource, i));
        }
end

rule "renewableResourceCapacity"
    when
        RenewableResourceUsedDay($resource : resource, $capacity : resourceCapacity, $usedDay : usedDay)
        accumulate(
            ResourceRequirement(resource == $resource,
                    $executionMode : executionMode,
                    $requirement : requirement)
            and Allocation(executionMode == $executionMode, $usedDay >= startDate, $usedDay < endDate);
            $used : sum($requirement);
            $used > $capacity
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0, $capacity - $used);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "totalProjectDelay"
    when
        Allocation(jobType == JobType.SINK, endDate != null, $endDate : endDate,
               $criticalPathEndDate : projectCriticalPathEndDate)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 0,  $criticalPathEndDate - $endDate);
end


rule "totalMakespan"
    when
        accumulate(
            Allocation(jobType == JobType.SINK, $endDate : endDate);
            $maxProjectEndDate : max($endDate)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, - (Integer) $maxProjectEndDate);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In task assignment, when you never want to run 2 jobs in parallel (so its a hard constraint, for all jobs), I'd probably make it a build-in hard constraint and basically model it like TSP.

If it's just pairs of specific jobs that shouldn't run in parallel, I'd have the variable listener detect that the 2 jobs would be run at the same time and delay the start time of the job that can start the latest. If they can both start at the same time, the one with the lowest id starts first and the other is delayed. This last bit is to avoid score corruption with incremental calculation.